# I want to have a list of subdirectories and then print it

Tags: python

I am very new to python, so sorry in advance if this question is too basic.

I want to read a list of subdirectories of a path and then print it. But instead of printing the names of the subdirectories it prints the characters:

```
products = []
dir_path = "/tmp"
for item in os.listdir(dir_path):
    products.extend(item)
index = 0
for product in products:
    print "%d %s" % ((index+1),product)
    index += 1
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `extend`, which takes an iterable and adds each element of it to a list, instead of `append`, which just adds the argument you pass to it. Like this:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a.extend([3,4])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> b.append([3,4])
>>> b
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

A string behaves like a list of characters. So `extend` adds each character of the item instead of the item itself.

You don't need to use a loop to construct a list, because `os.listdir` will return one anyway:

```
products = os.listdir(dir_path)
```

And you can write the second loop without incrementing the index yourself:

```
for idx, product in enumerate(products):
    print "%d %s" % ((index+1),product)
```

The `enumerate` function produces an object which generates just the pairs of (index, listitem) that you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(idx, f) for idx, f in enumerate(os.listdir('.'))]
```

EDIT (as suggested by @DSM):

```
list(enumerate(os.listdir('.')))
```

Comment: Isn't this just `list(enumerate(os.listdir('.')))`?  `enumerate` yields tuples; no need to pull it apart and then make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would point is

```
products.extend(item)
```

`extends` method extends the list by appending all the items in the given list. Since `strings` are iterable objects you just add all chars to the list. Change the method to `append`

The second thing is if you want to get an element and its index in a loop use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) method. Don't use counter variables.

```
for index, item in enumerate(products):
    print "%d %s" % (index, item)
```

And the last.
[os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns the all entries from specified directory. If you want to get subdirectories only

```
products = (d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d))
for i, product in enumerate(products):
    print "{0} {1}".format(i, product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add** the item to your list.

```
products.add(item)
```

`extend` adds all the items (characters in your case) of any *iterable* (the path) to a list.